# Which algorithm does Microsoft uses in their Cognitive Services' Face API?

Tags: algorithm, face-recognition, azure-cognitive-services, face-api

I have been working with MS Cognitive Services Face API for my high school science fair project and I am interested to know which algorithm is used.

I researched about different algorithms used for facial analysis and recognition, however, couldn't find the one used in this MS service.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about the inner workings of a possibly-closed-source library.

Comment: It wouldn't surprise me if it was a Bayesian network built with [Infer.NET](http://infernet.azurewebsites.net/)

Comment: Have you read this article about how MS Cognitive service detect faces? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/face/face-api-how-to-topics/howtodetectfacesinimage

Answer (score 0):

The service is not open-source, thus, you won't find details about its back-end.